# How to close a Vertx ReadStream from the client side?

Tags: java, vert.x

`WritesStream` has [`.end()`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/streams/WriteStream.html#end--). But I have not found anything similar for `ReadStream`.

I'd need to "unsubscribe" a client of a `ReadStream` from a never ending stream, after done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, setting a `null` handler does the trick:

```
readstream.handler(null);
```

Comment: Will this trigger exceptionHandler or endHandler of ReadStream?

Comment: I don't think so